# AngularJS factory: Best way to call parent in literal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have

```js
var test = {
  return {
    foo: function() {
      return 1
    },
    sub: {
      bar: function() {
        var foo = this.foo() // <--- here, does obviously not work
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the recommended and best way to access `foo()` from within `sub.bar()` ...?

To clarify, I want to split an angularjs service into sections.

---

"Real" code:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Service' function() {
  return {
    foo: function() {
       return 1
     },
     sub: {
       bar: function() {
         var foo = this.foo() // <--- here, does obviously not work
       }
     }
   }
 })
```

Comment: That `return` is misplaced, producing a syntax error. Please fix it to show a real object literal structure.

Comment: Just call  `test.foo()`?

Comment: @Bergi, riight, have updated with the real scenario

Comment: @Bergi, the problem is, that `Service` not is declared as a type you can refer to

Comment: You can introduce a local variable for it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an [angular factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe), you can Use the [Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript):

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Service' function() {
   function foo() {
     return 1
   }

   var sub = {
     bar: function() {
       var foo = foo()
     }
   }

   return {
     foo: foo,
     sub: sub
   }
 })
```

Comment: This is a great solution, need to refactor anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not ok:**

```
return {
  foo: function() {
    return 1
  }
}
```

You need to remove that `return` statement and within the function `bar` you can access the function `foo` using the name of the variable `test` as follow: `test.foo()`

```js
var test = {
  foo: function() {
    return 98989;
  },
  sub: {
    bar: function() {
      var foo = test.foo();
      console.log(foo);
    }
  }
};

test.sub.bar();
```

**Another way is using the function `bind`, but it's overkill:**

```js
var test = {
  foo: function() {
    return 98989;
  },
  sub: {
    bar: function() {
      var foo = this.foo(); // Using the object 'this'
      console.log(foo);
    }
  }
};

test.sub.bar.bind(test)();
```

**Now, you can declare a variable `service` and use that variable:**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Service'function() {
  var service = {
    foo: function() {
      return 1
    },
    sub: {
      bar: function() {
        var foo = service.foo();
                  ^^^^^^^
      }
    }
  };

  return service;
});
```